# QListWidget change part color of text

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlistwidget

Click Here to open the Sample Picture, the red Arrow is what I want, But the output just show all the code and didn't work just like the Blue Arrow does

[image]

I try use `< font color = red >...< /font > || < span >...< /span >` in QListWidget, but There didn't have any Effect

What I want is some thing like:

```
item1 <font color=red>apple</font> ("item1" black, "apple" will output as red color)
item2 <font color=green>durian</font> (durian will output as green color)
```

Can Anyone help?

Ps: Accually what I really want is the picture below:
[image]
When I type the word "cola", the list of QListwidget will Highlight/Change the color "%cola%" into Different color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QListWidget` by default does not render Html, but for this Qt has the delegate classes that allow customize the view.

In this case we use the following delegate:

```
#ifndef HTMLDELEGATE_H
#define HTMLDELEGATE_H

#include <QPainter>
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
#include <QTextDocument>

class HtmlDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    void paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex &index) const
    {
        QStyleOptionViewItem options = option;
        initStyleOption(&options, index);

        painter->save();

        QTextDocument doc;
        doc.setHtml(options.text);

        options.text = "";
        options.widget->style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ItemViewItem, &options, painter);

        painter->translate(options.rect.left(), options.rect.top());
        QRect clip(0, 0, options.rect.width(), options.rect.height());
        doc.drawContents(painter, clip);
        painter->restore();
    }

    QSize sizeHint ( const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index ) const
    {
        QStyleOptionViewItem options = option;
        initStyleOption(&options, index);

        QTextDocument doc;
        doc.setHtml(options.text);
        doc.setTextWidth(options.rect.width());
        return QSize(doc.idealWidth(), doc.size().height());
    }
};

#endif // HTMLDELEGATE_H
```

Then use the `setItemDelegate()` method of `QListWidget` as shown below:

```
ui->listWidget->setItemDelegate(new HtmlDelegate);
```

Obtaining what is shown in the following image:

[image]

The complete example can be found at the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/46189816-qlistwidget-change-part-color-of-text).