# Highlight search results in qtablewidget(select and highlight that text or character not all of the row or column)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I use method1 to find some text in qtablewidget rows.
method1 :

```
def FindItem(self):
    items = self.SuraBRS.findItems(
        self.SearchTbox.text(), QtCore.Qt.MatchContains)
    if items:
        results = '\n'.join(
            'row %d column %d' % (item.row() + 1, item.column() + 1)
            for item in items)
    else:
        results = 'Found Nothing'
    print(results)
```

Now I want to know how to highlight results or change their color.**I want to select and highlight that text or character not all of the row or column**.

Comment: No.It is not duplicate please read all the question

Comment: Data is text and I used MatchContains flag so it is not the cell

Comment: As I said it highlights the whole row or cell .Thats not what I want.But really thanks for your attention

Comment: I have tried it and it does not highlight the whole row but the items found, it seems to me that you are not implementing it correctly, it shows the code of the implementation that you use.

Comment: Please put your example here.

Comment: It does not work for you, so show what you've tried to point out where the problem is.

Comment: see my result with the code: `for item in items: item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(100,100,150))`  https://imgur.com/a/CapJTws

Comment: eyllanesc now you can see what is the result with your code.I have put an answer with your code.

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Comment: Hi   eyllanesc .Sorry that was late night I couldn't check and now can not check cause of job.It looks this one is OK but let me check it.Thanks for your answer again.

Comment: If my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, that is the best way to thank.

Comment: Sure I will do it if its correct no matter if it helps or not.I may want to find another way.

Comment: When I say it helps you, I mean that, because if it's correct, it will help you, otherwise it will not. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to change only a part of the text you must use an HTMLdelegate that I built in this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46191475/6622587), but it must be modified to avoid changing the html that can be the information and not the text that is desired:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

import random

try:
    from html import escape
except ImportError:
    from cgi import escape

words = [
    "Hello",
    "world",
    "Stack",
    "Overflow",
    "Hello world",
    """<font color="red">Hello world</font>""",
]


class HTMLDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(HTMLDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
        self.doc = QtGui.QTextDocument(self)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        substring = index.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
        painter.save()
        options = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
        self.initStyleOption(options, index)
        res = ""
        color = QtGui.QColor("orange")
        if substring:
            substrings = options.text.split(substring)
            res = """<font color="{}">{}</font>""".format(
                color.name(QtGui.QColor.HexRgb), substring
            ).join(list(map(escape, substrings)))
        else:
            res = escape(options.text)
        self.doc.setHtml(res)

        options.text = ""
        style = (
            QtWidgets.QApplication.style()
            if options.widget is None
            else options.widget.style()
        )
        style.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, options, painter)

        ctx = QtGui.QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.PaintContext()
        if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected:
            ctx.palette.setColor(
                QtGui.QPalette.Text,
                option.palette.color(
                    QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText
                ),
            )
        else:
            ctx.palette.setColor(
                QtGui.QPalette.Text,
                option.palette.color(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text),
            )

        textRect = style.subElementRect(QtWidgets.QStyle.SE_ItemViewItemText, options)

        if index.column() != 0:
            textRect.adjust(5, 0, 0, 0)

        thefuckyourshitup_constant = 4
        margin = (option.rect.height() - options.fontMetrics.height()) // 2
        margin = margin - thefuckyourshitup_constant
        textRect.setTop(textRect.top() + margin)

        painter.translate(textRect.topLeft())
        painter.setClipRect(textRect.translated(-textRect.topLeft()))
        self.doc.documentLayout().draw(painter, ctx)

        painter.restore()

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        return QSize(self.doc.idealWidth(), self.doc.size().height())


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("filter")
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(5, 5)
        hlay.addWidget(self.le)
        hlay.addWidget(self.button)
        lay.addLayout(hlay)
        lay.addWidget(self.table)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.find_items)
        self.table.setItemDelegate(HTMLDelegate(self.table))

        for i in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.table.columnCount()):
                it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(random.choice(words))
                self.table.setItem(i, j, it)

    def find_items(self):
        text = self.le.text()
        # clear
        allitems = self.table.findItems("", QtCore.Qt.MatchContains)
        selected_items = self.table.findItems(self.le.text(), QtCore.Qt.MatchContains)
        for item in allitems:
            item.setData(QtCore.Qt.UserRole, text if item in selected_items else None)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

PyQt4:

```py
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import random

try:
    from html import escape
except ImportError:
    from cgi import escape

words = [
    "Hello",
    "world",
    "Stack",
    "Overflow",
    "Hello world",
    """<font color="red">Hello world</font>""",
]


class HTMLDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(HTMLDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
        self.doc = QtGui.QTextDocument(self)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        substring = index.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
        if hasattr(substring, "toPyObject"):
            substring = str(substring.toPyObject())
        painter.save()
        options = QtGui.QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
        self.initStyleOption(options, index)
        text = index.data()
        if hasattr(text, "toPyObject"):
            text = str(text.toPyObject())
        res = ""
        color = QtGui.QColor("orange")
        if substring:
            substrings = text.split(substring)
            res = """<font color="{}">{}</font>""".format(color.name(), substring).join(
                list(map(escape, substrings))
            )
        else:
            res = escape(text)
        self.doc.setHtml(res)

        options.text = ""
        style = (
            QtGui.QApplication.style()
            # if options.widget is None
            # else options.widget.style()
        )
        style.drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, options, painter)

        ctx = QtGui.QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.PaintContext()
        if option.state & QtGui.QStyle.State_Selected:
            ctx.palette.setColor(
                QtGui.QPalette.Text,
                option.palette.color(
                    QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText
                ),
            )
        else:
            ctx.palette.setColor(
                QtGui.QPalette.Text,
                option.palette.color(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text),
            )

        textRect = (
            options.rect
        )  # style.subElementRect(QtGui.QStyle.SE_ItemViewItemText, options)

        if index.column() != 0:
            textRect.adjust(5, 0, 0, 0)

        thefuckyourshitup_constant = 4
        margin = (option.rect.height() - options.fontMetrics.height()) // 2
        margin = margin - thefuckyourshitup_constant
        textRect.setTop(textRect.top() + margin)

        painter.translate(textRect.topLeft())
        painter.setClipRect(textRect.translated(-textRect.topLeft()))
        self.doc.documentLayout().draw(painter, ctx)

        painter.restore()

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        return QSize(self.doc.idealWidth(), self.doc.size().height())


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        hlay = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.le = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("filter")
        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(5, 5)
        hlay.addWidget(self.le)
        hlay.addWidget(self.button)
        lay.addLayout(hlay)
        lay.addWidget(self.table)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.find_items)
        self.table.setItemDelegate(HTMLDelegate(self.table))

        for i in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.table.columnCount()):
                it = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(random.choice(words))
                self.table.setItem(i, j, it)

    def find_items(self):
        text = self.le.text()
        # clear
        allitems = self.table.findItems("", QtCore.Qt.MatchContains)
        selected_items = self.table.findItems(self.le.text(), QtCore.Qt.MatchContains)
        for item in allitems:
            item.setData(QtCore.Qt.UserRole, text if item in selected_items else None)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It select the whole cell

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question

Comment: try to select or highlight  "He" in all of your cell not the cell background.

Comment: I was mentioned NOT THE WHOLE CELL OR ROW isn't that clear

Comment: if you don't want to accept it then read my first comment .There I told you.

Comment: Hi eyllanesc .I checked that was use full ,But would You please explain more here.I knew that I have to change data like this but I want to know that if there are other possibilities to  use the widget signals and functions.

Comment: @MaziarParsijani 
I do not understand, why do you want signals?

Comment: @MaziarParsijani Qt implements the MVC pattern: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html , where there is a model (the information), a view (QTableWidget) and the controller that is the logic. In addition to the basics, a delegate is implemented to customize the view, and that is what I have used, on the other hand HTML allows us to change the color of the font in a simple way. The advantage is simplicity, I do not think you'll find another solution simpler than this.

Comment: @ eyllanesc . I did a lot of works in it but as you said it changed my table because of Arabic text format.Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @eyllanesc, Its works fine. .How to convert this into case insensitive.