# How to highlight a words in QTableWidget from a Searchlist

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I want to search a QTableWidget-Table by a list of words, if they've been found i want them to bee highlighted.

I tried to modify the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51613638/highlight-search-results-in-qtablewidgetselect-and-highlight-that-text-or-chara) so the table is beeing searched by a list of words, not just one. Unfortunatly my results keep getting overwritten. I always only get the result for the last word in the list.

Does anyone know how to modify the code so it will show the result of the whole list of words ?

Here is the code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import random
import html

words_1 = ["Hello dseerfd", "world sdfsdf sdfgsdf sdfsdf", "Stack dasdf", "Overflow", "Hello world", """<font color="red">Hello world</font>"""]

class HTMLDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(HTMLDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
        self.doc = QtGui.QTextDocument(self)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        substring = index.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
        painter.save()
        options = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
        self.initStyleOption(options, index)
        res = ""
        color = QtGui.QColor("red")
        if substring:
            substrings = options.text.split(substring)
            res = """<font color="{}">{}</font>""".format(color.name(QtGui.QColor.HexRgb), substring).join(list(map(html.escape, substrings)))
        else:
            res = html.escape(options.text)
        self.doc.setHtml(res)

        options.text = ""
        style = QtWidgets.QApplication.style() if options.widget is None \
            else options.widget.style()
        style.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, options, painter)

        ctx = QtGui.QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.PaintContext()
        if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected:
            ctx.palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Text, option.palette.color(
                QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText))
        else:
            ctx.palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Text, option.palette.color(
                QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text))

        textRect = style.subElementRect(
            QtWidgets.QStyle.SE_ItemViewItemText, options)

        if index.column() != 0:
            textRect.adjust(5, 0, 0, 0)

        the_constant = 4
        margin = (option.rect.height() - options.fontMetrics.height()) // 2
        margin = margin - the_constant
        textRect.setTop(textRect.top() + margin)

        painter.translate(textRect.topLeft())
        painter.setClipRect(textRect.translated(-textRect.topLeft()))
        self.doc.documentLayout().draw(painter, ctx)

        painter.restore()


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(5, 5)
        lay.addLayout(hlay)
        lay.addWidget(self.table)



        self.table.setItemDelegate(HTMLDelegate(self.table))

        for i in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.table.columnCount()):
                it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(random.choice(words_1))
                self.table.setItem(i, j, it)


        text_list = ['ello', 'ack']
        # clear
        allitems = self.table.findItems("", QtCore.Qt.MatchContains)

        selected_items =[]
        for words in text_list:
            for item in allitems:
                selected_items = self.table.findItems(words, QtCore.Qt.MatchContains)
                selected_items.append(self.table.findItems(words, QtCore.Qt.MatchContains)) ## i tried to make a list which is beeing appened but using this list it returns only the same as the input

                item.setData(QtCore.Qt.UserRole, words if item in selected_items else None)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the previous case I wanted to filter the cases so as not to have to paint unnecessarily but in this case because it was more complex I decided to implement the highlight logic using `QTextCharFormat` and not HTML as I show below:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import random

words = ["Hello dseerfd", "world sdfsdf sdfgsdf sdfsdf", "Stack dasdf", "Overflow", "Hello world", """<font color="red">Hello world</font>"""]

class HighlightDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(HighlightDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
        self.doc = QtGui.QTextDocument(self)
        self._filters = []

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        painter.save()
        options = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
        self.initStyleOption(options, index)
        self.doc.setPlainText(options.text)
        self.apply_highlight()
        options.text = ""
        style = QtWidgets.QApplication.style() if options.widget is None \
            else options.widget.style()
        style.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, options, painter)

        ctx = QtGui.QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.PaintContext()
        if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected:
            ctx.palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Text, option.palette.color(
                QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText))
        else:
            ctx.palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Text, option.palette.color(
                QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text))

        textRect = style.subElementRect(
            QtWidgets.QStyle.SE_ItemViewItemText, options)

        if index.column() != 0:
            textRect.adjust(5, 0, 0, 0)

        the_constant = 4
        margin = (option.rect.height() - options.fontMetrics.height()) // 2
        margin = margin - the_constant
        textRect.setTop(textRect.top() + margin)

        painter.translate(textRect.topLeft())
        painter.setClipRect(textRect.translated(-textRect.topLeft()))
        self.doc.documentLayout().draw(painter, ctx)

        painter.restore()

    def apply_highlight(self):
        cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(self.doc)
        cursor.beginEditBlock()
        fmt = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        fmt.setForeground(QtCore.Qt.red)
        for f in self.filters():
            highlightCursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(self.doc)
            while not highlightCursor.isNull() and not highlightCursor.atEnd():
                highlightCursor = self.doc.find(f, highlightCursor)
                if not highlightCursor.isNull():
                    highlightCursor.mergeCharFormat(fmt)
        cursor.endEditBlock()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(list)
    def setFilters(self, filters):
        if self._filters == filters: return
        self._filters = filters

    def filters(self):
        return self._filters

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(30, 6)
        self._delegate = HighlightDelegate(self.table)
        self.table.setItemDelegate(self._delegate)
        for i in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.table.columnCount()):
                it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(random.choice(words))
                self.table.setItem(i, j, it)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

        le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        le.textChanged.connect(self.on_textChanged)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(le)
        lay.addWidget(self.table)

        le.setText("ello ack")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_textChanged(self, text):
        self._delegate.setFilters(list(set(text.split())))
        self.table.viewport().update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: You saved my day! One question, though: I've adopted your code to my QTableView with custom QStyledItemDelegate, but then the style sheet (which I set via `QApplication.instance().setStyleSheet(...)`) is not applied to table items (i.e. color, background-color, border,... are all ignored). Is it possible to tell the custom delegate to only highlight matches, without touching any style options specified in the app's style sheet?