# Setting the Highlight color within a QStyledItemDelegate on a QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyside, pyside2, qtablewidget, qstyleditemdelegate

I am referencing code as written by eyllanesc here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53357083/3950707

When a cell on my `QTableWidget` is selected I want the default select colour displayed:
[image]

However, after setting the `initStyleOption`, this lighter colour displayed:

[image]

I am not certain what I need to change in order to set a new `Highlight` colour.
Is this something I need to change in option before it is passed into a `QStyleOptionViewItem`, or is it something I need to change in a `QPalette` or `QStyle` somewhere?

I know I can used `painter.fillRect()` to set a colour to the background, but this then overloads the default style, removing the grey dotted lines from around the cell.
I'm hoping that I can avoid the need to rebuild everything in paint by setting the colour for `Highlight` similarly to a `stylesheet`'s hover, checked etc.

Below is the abridged code I am using.

```
class CustomDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDelegate, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.doc = QtGui.QTextDocument(self)
        self.text_edit = None

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):

        painter.save()

        options = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem(option)

        self.initStyleOption(options, index)

        self.doc.setPlainText(options.text)

        # Resets option text
        options.text = ""

        style = QtWidgets.QApplication.style() if options.widget is None \
            else options.widget.style()

        #print(option.palette.highlight())
        #print(style.standardPalette().highlight())
        #print (dir(style.standardPalette()))

        style.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, options, painter)

        # Set text colour
        paint_context = QtGui.QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.PaintContext()
        if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected:
            paint_context.palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Text, option.palette.color(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText))
            #painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QColor("green"))

        else:
            paint_context.palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Text, option.palette.color(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text))
            option.palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Background, QtCore.Qt.black)

        painter.translate(text_rect.topLeft())
        painter.setClipRect(text_rect.translated(-text_rect.topLeft()))

        self.doc.documentLayout().draw(painter, paint_context)

        painter.restore()

        return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I was unable to find how to change the style of a control element, but adding the options widget into `drawControl` seems to return the correct colors.

```
style.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, options, painter)
```

change to:

```
style.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, options, painter, options.widget)
```