# QTableWidget ItemDelegate breaks selection style

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qitemdelegate

In the following Python 2.7, PyQt4 example, I generate 2 QTableWidgets.  Table1 has no ItemDelegate and the table2 has HTMLDelegate.

Selected background color works if the table has focus, but when the table loses focus, the blue selection turns gray on table2.  I want table2 selection to work like table1 when focus is lost.

How can I maintain blue selection appearance regardless of focus when using itemdelegate?

[image]

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)   

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import random

from html import escape

words = [
    "Hello",
    "world",
    "Stack",
    "Overflow",
    "Hello world",
]

class HTMLDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(HTMLDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
        self.doc = QtGui.QTextDocument(self)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):

        col = index.column()
        row = index.row()

        painter.save()

        options = QtGui.QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
        self.initStyleOption(options, index)

        text = index.data()

        self.doc.setHtml(text)

        options.text = ""
        style = (
            QtGui.QApplication.style()
        )
        style.drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, options, painter)

        ctx = QtGui.QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.PaintContext()

        if option.state & QtGui.QStyle.State_Selected:
            ctx.palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Text, option.palette.color(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText), )
        else:
            ctx.palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Text, option.palette.color(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text), )

        textRect = (options.rect)  

        constant = 4
        margin = (option.rect.height() - options.fontMetrics.height()) // 2
        margin = margin - constant
        textRect.setTop(textRect.top() + margin)

        painter.translate(textRect.topLeft())
        painter.setClipRect(textRect.translated(-textRect.topLeft()))
        self.doc.documentLayout().draw(painter, ctx)

        painter.restore()

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        return QSize(self.doc.idealWidth(), self.doc.size().height())


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        hlay = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.table1 = QtGui.QTableWidget(4, 2)
        self.table2 = QtGui.QTableWidget(4, 2)
        lay.addLayout(hlay)
        lay.addWidget(self.table1)
        lay.addWidget(self.table2)

        # define itemdelegate for table1, but not for table2
        self.table2.setItemDelegate(HTMLDelegate(self.table2))

        # fill table1
        for i in range(self.table1.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.table1.columnCount()):
                it = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(random.choice(words))
                self.table1.setItem(i, j, it)

        # fill table2
        for i in range(self.table2.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.table2.columnCount()):
                it = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(random.choice(words))
                self.table2.setItem(i, j, it)        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    app.setStyle("Plastique")   # set style

    stylesheet = """
    QPushButton:hover, QComboBox:hover
    {
        background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #cbc9c5, stop: 1 #b9b7b5);
        border: 2px solid #78879b;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
    QTableWidget::item:selected 
    {
        background: #0078d7;  
        color: white;
    }
    QTableWidget
    {
        font: 9pt "Segoe UI"; 
    }
    QHeaderView
    {
        font: 9pt "Segoe UI"; 
    }
    """    

    app.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)       

    myapp = Widget()     
    myapp.show()           

    rc = app.exec_()

    myapp.close()

    sys.exit(rc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `QStyleOptionViewItem`, which in Qt4 is a very basic class, while what you'll need is [`QStyleOptionViewItemV4`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qstyleoptionviewitemv4.html), which implements a lot of useful things, including decorations (as in item icon) and their positioning, the item position according to other items, and, most importantly, the widget the delegate is used in and its full QStyle painting capabilities.

The `style.drawControl` method, like most of QStyle methods, also has a `widget` argument; it is normally ignored, but is very important in this kind of situations, expecially when there are stylesheets at play.

I suggest you to use the `option`'s class of the `paint()` method as a reference to create your own option, which will automatically use the latest QStyleOption available for view item, and will also make a possible future transition to Qt5 much easier.

Keep in mind that, according to the documentation (which is somehow obscure about that), the widget property is available only from version 3 of QStyleOptionViewItem, but according to my tests the correct background painting will fail anyway with that version. If, for any reason, you're stuck with a *very* old version of Qt which doesn't provide QStyleOptionViewItemV4, I'm afraid that the only option you'll have is to keep the background color reference somewhere (there's no way to access to stylesheet colors from code, and it doesn't match the QTableView `Highlight` palette role) and manually paint the background by yourself.

```
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        #...
        newOption = option.__class__(option)
        self.initStyleOption(newOption, index)
        #...
        style = newOption.widget.style() if newOption.widget else QtGui.QApplication.style()
        style.drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, newOption, painter, newOption.widget)
        # ...
```

PS: I'd suggest you to not use too similar names for objects: I actually lost sometime finding the source of the problem because I often got confused between "option" and "option**s**": that's why I changed it, which is much better for readability and debugging purposes too.

Comment: I originally got this code from another great stack overflow user @ellaynesc ... https://stackoverflow.com/q/57062107/259538

Comment: Yes, but that code is based on Qt5, which implements everything QStyleOptionViewItemV4 uses. As said, if you use the plain QStyleOptionViewItem on Qt4 you will face the issues you're talking about.

Comment: @ellaynesc provided a Qt5 and Qt4 versions of source on his post at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51615332/259538.  I am hoping to find a solution to the selection style issue in Qt4 because my environment requires it and I can't move to Qt5 at this time.

Comment: Sorry, didn't remember that part. Anyway, I still don't understand what's wrong with my solution...

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your solution... I just hadn't tested it yet.  You have impressive PyQt skill, thanks!

Comment: Ah ok :-) You're welcome! Anyway, you can use `QTableWidget::item:selected:!active` to control the background of a selected item when the widget has no focus, but the widget parameter to `drawControl()` and v4 of StyleOption are still required, and you'll need to use `option.palette.color(QtGui.QPalette.Active if option.widget.hasFocus() else QtGui.QPalette.Inactive` to ensure that the right text color is used.